# Sublime does not see env variables

Tags: sublimetext, sublimelinter

When running sublime from desctop it does not see my PERL5LIB environment variable.
When running it from terminal - everithing is OK.
I set my variables in .bashrc and .bash_profile.

```
import os
>>> os.environ['SHELL']
'/bin/bash'
>>> os.environ['PERL5LIB']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./os.py", line 676, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'PERL5LIB'
```

this makes trouble with linting and build system - I can not link and build becase of perl does not see libraries.

How to fix env variable?

Comment: Looks more like Python than Perl. Are you sure you've the right tags here?

Comment: sublime use phyton. I use phyton commands (CTRL+`) to show that PERL5LIB variable is not setted up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bad news](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path?answertab=votes#tab-top):

> The Ubuntu desktop session is no longer affected by .profile.
>   Additionally bash doesn't parse .profile if either .bash_profile or
>   .bash_login exists.

[You can work around:](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables)

> **Launching desktop application with an environment variable**
>
> You can add an environment variable to an application by editing its
>   .desktop file. For example, to run "digiKam" with the environment
>   variable APPMENU_DISPLAY_BOTH=1, find the corresponding
>   digikam.desktop file and add the setting of the variable, via the env
>   command, to the entry "Exec":
>
> ```
> Exec=env APPMENU_DISPLAY_BOTH=1 digikam -caption "%c" %i
> ```

or do small script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
/opt/sublime_text/sublime_text
```